# Could not find function "zip.file.extract"

Tags: r, unzip, zip

```
library(utils)

a<-zip.file.extract("\\1\\1.csv",zipname="drivers.zip")
```

> Error: could not find function "zip.file.extract"

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

`zip.file.extract()` is a defunct function as of R 2.14 (see `?"utils-defunct"` help page or try brining up the `?zip.file.extract` help page). Use the `unzip()` function instead. Perhaps

```
unzip("drivers.zip", files="\1\1.csv")
```

or you can omit the `files=` to extract all files in the zip archive to the current working directory.

Comment: a<-unzip("drivers.zip","\\drivers\\1\\1.csv")
Warning message:
In unzip("drivers.zip", "\\drivers\\1\\1.csv") :
  requested file not found in the zip file. I am sure the file is there. As under the zip file is a folder "drivers", in "drivers" a folder "1", and in "1" a file "1.csv"

Comment: Well, I don't have your file so I can't test, but perhaps take of the leading slash.

Comment: a<-unzip("drivers.zip","drivers\\1\\1.csv");               the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the internal names of the zip file. I was facing same problem. Then, I discovered that it was related to a multibyte character.

Comment: It's hard to believe that your answer addresses the same question that the OP had ... ???